# forEach and setState for an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I print my existing state like console.log(this.state) I have

`{'abc-sorted':false, 'def-sorted': 'asc', 'someotherstuff-sorted': true, show: true}`

What I want to do is set all state that end with state key of '-sorted', what should I do?

I did this 'ugly' thing.

```
Object.keys(this.state).filter(o=>{
                return o.endsWith('sorted') 
            }).forEach(o2 => {
                this.setState({
                    [o2]: false
                })
            })
```

Any alternative to this? This caused unwanted rendering.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to generate an object first. Then set your state. This way you will only set it once.

```
const newState = {};

Object.keys(this.state).forEach(key => {
    if (key.endsWith('sorted')) {
      newState[key] = false;
    }
});

this.setState(newState);
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this can work for you ...

I my case snapshot is the object. Inside my constructor I have

```
  this.state = {
    docs: []
  }
```

and I did

```
  snapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
    this.setState({
      docs: [...this.state.docs, doc]
    })
  }.bind(this))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could instead of calling `setState` in a loop call it once

```
const stateUpdates = {};
Object.keys(this.state).filter(o=>{
                return o.endsWith('sorted') 
            }).forEach(o2 => {
                stateUpdates[o2] = false
            })
this.setState(stateUpdates)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and prevent immutability in the state:

```js
const state = {
  'abc-sorted': false,
  'def-sorted': 'asc',
  'someotherstuff-sorted': true,
  show: true,
}

const containsSorted = key => key.indexOf('-sorted') !== -1

const result = Object.keys(state).reduce((prev, curr) => {
  return {
    ...prev,
    [curr]: containsSorted(curr) ? false : state[curr],
  }
}, {})

console.log(result)
// this.setState(result)
```