# React update state array object single property

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following method:

```
  addWidget = (index) => {
    var currentState = this.state;

    if(currentState.availableWidgets[index].pos === 'start'){

      // add it at the start
      for(var i = 0; i < currentState.widgets.length; i++){
        this.setState({
          widgets: [
            ...currentState.widgets,
            currentState.widgets.x = 5
          ]

        })
      }
    }
    else {
      var endX = currentState.widgets.reduce((endX, w) => endX + w.w, 0)
      if (endX === 12) endX = 0

      this.setState({
        widgets: currentState.widgets.concat({
          ...currentState.availableWidgets[index],
          i: uuid(),
          x: endX,
          y: Infinity,
        })
      })
    }

    console.log(currentState.widgets);
  }
```

and the state is:

```
class DashboardContainer extends React.Component {
  state = {
    widgets: [],
    availableWidgets: [
      {
        type: 'compliance-stats',
        config: {

        },
        w: 1,
        h: 1,
        pos: 'start',
      },
      {
        type: 'compliance-stats',
        config: {

        },
        w: 3,
        h: 2,
      }
    ]
  }
  ...
```

I am trying to update the "x" property of each object inside "widgets" by doing so:

```
  for(var i = 0; i < currentState.widgets.length; i++){
    this.setState({
      widgets: [
        ...currentState.widgets,
        currentState.widgets.x = 5
      ]

    })
  }
```

I am aware of setting the state inside a loop is not good at all. However I am currently getting an error.

[image]

I am importing widgets in:

```
const Dashboard = ({ widgets, onLayoutChange, renderWidget }) => {
  const layouts = {
    lg: widgets,
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <ResponsiveReactGridLayout 
        layouts={layouts} 
        onLayoutChange={onLayoutChange} 
        cols={{ lg: 12 }} 
        breakpoints={{lg: 1200}}>
          {
            widgets.map(
              (widget) => 
              <div key={widget.i}>
                {renderWidget(widget)}
              </div>
            )
          }
      </ResponsiveReactGridLayout>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Same question from me too

Comment: Possible Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47937369/foreach-and-setstate-for-an-array/47937460#47937460

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably better to change the `widgets` and then `setState` only once:

```
const changedWidgets = currentState.widgets.map(w => ({ ...w, x: 5 }));
this.setState({ widgets: changedWidgets });
```

Comment: This is a great solution but it's complaining about the spread operator

Comment: I had to add a return "w => { return {...w, x: w.x + currentState.availableWidgets[index].w } }"

Comment: Fixed the return of the object literal

Answer (score 0):

The spread operator inside an array will concatenate a new value onto the array, so by seting widgets state to `[ ...currentState.widgets, currentState.widgets.x = 5 ]` what you're actually trying to do is `currentState.widgets.concate(currentState.widgets.x = 5)` which is throwing your error.

If you would like to modify the value inside an array you should map out the array and then modify the objects inside the array like so.

```
const widgets = currentState.widgets.map(widget => { ...widget, x: 5})
this.setState({ widgets })
```

Comment: Spread operator: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator